# error while converting MatOfKeyPoints to json string

Tags: android, json, opencv, gson

i am trying to convert a MatOfKeyPoints object in opencv android to json string .

MatOfKeyPoint refKeypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();

```
    Mat refDescriptors = new Mat();
    FeatureDetector orbFeatureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
    orbFeatureDetector.detect(grayMat, refKeypoints);
    Mat Out = new Mat();
    DescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    descriptorExtractor.compute(grayMat, refKeypoints, refDescriptors);
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(grayMat, refKeypoints, Out,new Scalar(2,254,255),Features2d.DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    //System.out.println(refKeypoints);
    Utils.matToBitmap(Out,grayBitmap);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(grayBitmap);
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();

    if(refKeypoints.isContinuous()){
        int cols = refKeypoints.cols();
        int rows = refKeypoints.rows();
        int elemSize = (int) refKeypoints.elemSize();

        byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];

        refKeypoints.get(0, 0, data);

        obj.addProperty("rows", refKeypoints.rows());
        obj.addProperty("cols", refKeypoints.cols());
        obj.addProperty("type", refKeypoints.type());

        // We cannot set binary data to a json object, so:
        // Encoding data byte array to Base64.
        String dataString = new String(Base64.encode(data, Base64.DEFAULT));

        obj.addProperty("data", dataString);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(obj);

    } else {

    }
```

but i get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaDhv.png)